# Python for loop correct syntax explanation

Tags: python, for-loop

I've seen this:

```
for item in range(6): 
    print item
```

but what is the name of this and how do i print the "item" in this new for loop

```
[item for item in range(6)]
```

Comment: That's a "list comprehension".  You *don't* print anything in it, the whole point is to generate a list by transforming a sequence.

Comment: Generally the first is used to do stuff (like printing), while the second is used to describe stuff (like lists).

Comment: `[print(item) for item in range(6)]` I don't know why so many are so adamant about not printing with this format, its your life your code, if you want to thats a one-liner that will print it.

Comment: Using print in the loop comprehension is fine IMHO, just dont be alarmed if you use it in the REPL and see a list of `None`s printed out afterward.

Comment: Is this Python2 only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a list comprehension and you can print the list of items you generate in it  this way:

```
print([item for item in range(6)])
```

and the output will be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or, if you want to print each item in a separate line:

```
[print(item) for item in range(6)]
```

will give you:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: could put the print inside as well `[print(item) for item in range(6)]` same same different

Comment: Cheers! I just edited my answer to reflect that and saw your comment :)

Comment: How about `print(*(item for item in range(6)))`? No real need to create a `list`.